Remove checkbox created in a function using Tkinter
I have the below code. Essentially I am trying to write a programme, with a GUI, that takes a list/dictionary of items, and allows me to select the ones I want. This will then add the selected items to a new list/dictionary and move on.
This is my code -
    import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


def main():
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Simple App")
        self.geometry('500x300')

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        frame = InputForm(self)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)


class InputForm(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.checkboxes = {}  # Dictionary to store checkboxes and their states (checked/unchecked)
        self.count = 0
        self.dict_keys = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]
        self.selected = {}

        # Create checkboxes from your list
        for item in self.dict_keys:
            self.create_check_box(item)

        self.entry_btn = ttk.Button(self, text="Add", command=self.add_to_list)
        self.entry_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.entry_btn2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Clear", command=self.clear_list)
        self.entry_btn2.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.entry_btn3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Continue", command=self._continue)
        self.entry_btn3.grid(row=0, column=3)

    def create_check_box(self, item):
        int_var = tk.IntVar(value=0)  # Set initial value to 0 (unchecked)
        checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text=item, variable=int_var, command=lambda: self.check_state(item))
        checkbutton.grid(row=self.count + 1, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.checkboxes[item] = int_var
        self.count += 1

    def check_state(self, item):
        # You can use this function to track checkbox state changes (optional)
        state = self.checkboxes[item].get()
        print(f"Checkbox '{item}' is {state}")  # Example

    def add_to_list(self, _event=None):
        # Implement logic to add selected items to a list
        selected_items = [item for item, var in self.checkboxes.items() if var.get() == 1]
        print(f"Selected items: {selected_items}")  # Example

    def clear_list(self):
        # Reset all checkboxes to unchecked
        for var in self.checkboxes.values():
            var.set(0)

    def _continue(self):
        if messagebox.askyesno(title='Continue?', message='Are you sure you want to continue?'):
            self.selected = {}
            for key, value in self.checkboxes.items():
                if value.get() == 1:
                    self.selected[key] = 'Selected'
            print(self.selected)
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I'm trying to get it so when i click CONTINUE Either the window destroys and creates a new one. Or the checkboxes are removed from the current window. Any help would be appreciated

I don't have experience with tkinter, but looking it up it seems you should call checkbutton.destroy(). I'd do that by adding checkbuttons = [] in __init__(), and looping through and destroying each of them in _continue().

Thank you for this. This is exactly what I did in the end and it worked
